# Clarification on private, public, protected

Tags: c++

I wanted to get a clearer idea of the differences between `public`, `private` and `protected` members in c++.

-Anything that is `public` is available to all derived classes of a base class, and the `public` variables and data for each object of both the base and derived class is accessible by code outside the class.

-Not only are the functions and variables marked `private` not accessible by code outside the specific object in which that data appears, but `private` variables and functions are not inherited

-Variables and functions marked `protected` are inherited by derived classes; however, these derived classes hide the data from code outside of any instance of the object

I guess I'm not really clear on the differences between `private` and `protected`.  Are `private` members accessible only to the method of the `class`?

Is there access to `private` members of a class by any function defined outside the `class`?

Comment: Here is an excellent link that explains all the nuances and subtleties of those accessors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: I'd add that `private` components of a class are indeed also part of derived classes. They just can't be accessed (except if there is a `protected` or `public` accessor function).